# MyEclipse's class file

Tags: myeclipse

I'm using MyEclipse and want to change to Eclipse directly, but I found that the .class file generated by MyEclipse and Eclipse are different. First, I found the JDK version are different (I reference http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file to find offset 6-7). But after use same JDK the .class are still different.

I also use Java de-compiler for the 2 .class files, but get the same result, is there any suggestion for me? Because it's an old system, if the class files are different, I have no confidence to do migration.

Answer (score 0):

The Java functionality in MyEclipse is the same as eclipse, at the relevant version. MyEclipse 2013 is based on eclipse 3.8.2 (though eclipse 3.8.2 is a bit more difficult to find than 4.2.2), MyEclipse 10 is based on eclipse 3.7.2. Eclipse will be using the Java compiler in the JRE specified for the project (which may be different from the default specified for the workspace). You should also check the Java compliance level for the project (or the workspace default, if there is no project specific level specified).